# Capture group if it exists between two other words

Tags: regex

Let's take this regex:

```
/start[\S\s]+?(captureme)?[\S\s]+?end/g
```

and test in on this text:

```
case 1:
start
captureme
suffix
end

case 2:
start
prefix
captureme
suffix
end
```

1) Please explain to me, why does "captureme" get captured into a group in case 1 and doesn't get captured in case 2?

2) What should I use if I want "captureme" text to be captured if it exists between closest "start" and "end" regardless of anything between them?

Note that I need this regex to also match if "captureme" is missing:

```
case 3:
start
prefix
suffix
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example of what I need to be matched and captured http://prntscr.com/f8pivk

Comment: Here is closest I got to solution: start(\n.*?){0,10}(captureme)?(\n.*?){0,10}end
This matches as I want, but has a line limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around in regex sandbox and this worked for me perfectly:

```
start[\S\s]+?(?:(captureme)[\S\s]+?)?end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use a conditional with a negative lookahead:

```
(?(?!start)(captureme)|end)
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/E6ZXZe/1

The reason your regex doesn't match is because of the quantifier `?` which indicates "match between zero and one times", if you take that out of (capture) then it should work, although it's easier probably to do the condintional if your regex engine allows it.

Comment: But I need to match all the text between "start ... end" (including those words), while also capturing "captureme" if it exists.

Comment: @I'L'I Yes, but now case 1.5 and 2 are recognized as one match in your example. Can I somehow make it capture like this? http://prntscr.com/f8pivk

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I managed to find what I need by trial and error: start[\S\s]+?(?:(captureme)[\S\s]+?)?end